# I want to show my own message while extracting a sfx archive

Tags: sfx

I am working on an software installer which should be fully unattended, for this purpose i want to make SFX archives for software and want to show my own message by replacing the SFX default window, i searched on Google for this purpose but didn't found exact solution to my problem. The help i found is that the sfx windows gets fully hidden or the dialog boxes comes with extraction process but i have seen some sfx archives which only show a bar like comments or tool tips in which a customized message is given. i worked hard to do it in the sfx creation option through winrar but since two months i dint found any reasonable solution. on this site i found a matching question but there is c++ involved in the solution, i want to know that is there a simple solution of my problem within the sfx option in winrar or somewhere other, i will be really thankful is any one most respected of you can understand and get my question and answer it thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

See e.g. [Customizing WinRAR SFX for customized installers](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/35532-customizing-winrar-sfx-for-customized-installers/) . The idea is to replace resources inside an SFX module.